# how to upload file to document and library in liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay

how to upload the file to document and library in **liferay 6.1**

i am using

```
addFileEntry(long userId, long groupId, long repositoryId, long folderId, String sourceFileName, String mimeType, String title, String description, String changeLog, long fileEntryTypeId, Map<String,Fields> fieldsMap, File file, InputStream is, long size, ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

of `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil` class

Comment: looks good, you might want to give more information about the parameters that you pass and what your problem is

Comment: Yeah, pls elaborate on what cause you the trouble. You could also take a look on `DLAppLocalServiceUtil`.

Answer (score 0):

public void fileUpload(String filename) throws Exception {

```
    // file
    File file = new File(filename);

    if (file.exists()) {


        long folderId = 12344;
        long repositoryId = 10180;

        // filename
        String sourceFileName = file.getName();

        // mimetype
        String mimeType = "";
        if (sourceFileName.substring(sourceFileName.length() - 4)
                .compareToIgnoreCase(".pdf") == 0) {
            mimeType = "application/pdf";
        } else {
            if (sourceFileName.substring(sourceFileName.length() - 4)
                    .compareToIgnoreCase(".xls") == 0) {
                mimeType = "application/xls";
            }
        }

        // for title
        String title = file.getName();
        // for description
        String description = file.getName();
        // changeLog
        String changeLog = "";
        // fileEntryTypeId
        long fileEntryTypeId = 0;

        // for fieldMap
        Fields feild = null;
        Map<java.lang.String, com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.storage.Fields> fieldsMap = new HashMap<java.lang.String, com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.storage.Fields>();
        fieldsMap.put("", feild);

        // for InputStream
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // for file size
        double bytes = file.length();
        long size = (long) (bytes / 1024);

        // service Context Object
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        Date date = new Date();
        ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
        serviceContext.setUuid(uuid);
        serviceContext.setCreateDate(date);
        serviceContext.setModifiedDate(date);

        // PermissionChecking
        PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(10196);
        PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil
                .create(UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(10196));
        PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);

        DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(repositoryId, folderId,
                sourceFileName, mimeType, title, description, changeLog,
                is, size, serviceContext);
        /*
         * DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, groupId,
         * repositoryId, folderId, sourceFileName, mimeType, title,
         * description, changeLog, fileEntryTypeId, fieldsMap, file, is,
         * size, serviceContext);
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question with more clarification rather than posting an answer - also, you're using a lot of magic numbers (ids) in here, it makes sense to also describe how you got them. After all, your code might work perfectly but write to some place that does not match your expectation - so that the content is there but you can't find it. And last, you just imply that it doesn't work but you don't state what doesn't work: Can't you find your data? Do you get an exception? Or do you only get partial content (e.g. 1‰  `long size = (long) (bytes / 1024);`)